# The wi-fi on my HP Envy 15 doesn't work

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, internet

I recently dual booted my HP Envy 15 with Windows and Ubuntu 16.04 for some university projects, but I cannot use the Wi-Fi on Ubuntu. There isn't even an option to connect to the Wi-fi.
I downloaded, installed and selected the the Wi-Fi drivers shown in the "Additional Drivers" section in the settings but that still didn't work for me.
I ran this command in the Terminal

```
lshw -C Network
```

This returned the following results

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:b5500000-b5507fff
*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 10
       serial: 8c:dc:d4:8b:e3:b6
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.1.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:42 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b5404000-b5404fff memory:b5400000-b5403fff
```

I tried these commands

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 
rfkill list
```

And first command returned this

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Broadcom BCM43142 802.11bgn 1x1 WiFi Adapter + BT 4.0 combo adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:2230]
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
```

And the second returned this.

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

I'm new to Linux and I don't know anything about this OS. I would really appreciate it if someone helps me resolve this issue, I hate connecting to the Ethernet cable every time I need to use the Internet.